# How to get Session Value in C#

Tags: c#, session, razor

I have a session set in my browser and I would like to retrieve the value of it:

[image]

I have tried:

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["nolangask"].ToString()
```

and

```
@Session["nolangask"].ToString()
```

And a few other combinations that visual studio just outright rejected before I tried to run them. I feel I am probably missing something very basic...

Comment: Chrome session storage does not show server side session. It is not possible. How do you assign value to Session ? Share it.

Comment: I used JavaScript 
` function setsessionlang() {
    sessionStorage.nolangask = true;
  }`
I realise I have got server side and local sessions mixed up...

Comment: what you are doing is server side programming - means you asking for required value from your server and i think you stored on you local machine. solution is you have to get value (like you doing) but on client side may be with javascript.

Comment: @Ginger Squirrel, do you want to use server side session ? Explain what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, I moved the functionality to client side. I have a complex multilingual site that has a pop-up appear if the users browser language doesn't match that of the site to give them the option of changing the language. The content of the popup is generated server side and I added the option for the user to dismiss this pop-up by storing a session, I wanted to access that session server side to prevent the popup code being written out.

Instead I have just added some JavaScript to check if the session is there, if it is, it blocks the popup.